# Move last histogram tick label to left of bar

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a plot where the 5th bar is incorrectly placed right next to the 4th bar. What should I change?
My `small_ax_0` pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
INDEX    0
0      1  5.0
1  10001  4.0
2  20001  5.0
3  30001  5.0
4  40001  5.0
5  50001  4.0
6  60001  1.0
7  70001  4.0
8  80001  0.0
9  90001  4.0
```

Here is my code:

```
plt.hist(small_ax_0[0])
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=100)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=100) 
plt.xlabel('Position', fontsize=100)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=100)
plt.title('My Plot',  fontsize = 150) ##
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='grey', linestyle='dotted')
plt.xticks( rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas [visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

```
df['0'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, `hist` returns 10 bins, equally spaced along the range of your data. So in this case, the data ranges from 0 to 5, and spacing between bins is 0.5. If you just want to plot the number of occurrences of each number, I suggest using `np.unique()` and use a `bar` plot:

```
import numpy as np
nums, freq = np.unique(small_ax_0[0], return_counts=True)
plt.bar(nums, freq)
```

and you get a figure, where the bars are centered around each number.

[image]